# Undeclared variable configId on TRIGGER

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER input_verification AFTER INSERT ON InputHistory
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NO EXISTS (SELECT * FROM InputHistory JOIN Intput on InputHistory.inputId = Input.inputId WHERE InputHistory.inputId = NEW.inputId AND InputHistory.inputHistoryOrderNumber=Input.inputOrderNumber AND InputHistory.inputHistoryStatus >= 300)
BEGIN
    DECLARE configId INTEGER;
    SELECT Input.inputConfigurationId INTO configId FROM Input JOIN InputHistory ON Input.inputId = InputHistory.inputId WHERE NEW.inputId=Input.inputId;
    UPDATE Configuration SET configurationReady = true WHERE configurationId= configId;
END
```

Comment: WHEN NO EXISTS  - what's this? not mysql anyway..and why is it before the begin?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to set the boolean  configurationReady to true when none of the inputs matches the condition in ()

Comment: Fair enough - would you like to answer my first comment?

Comment: probably I saw it on the wrong documentation, because i can't find it now. do you know wich is the right sytanx to do so?